# Put LinearLayout on top of ListView

Tags: android

I want to place a linearlayout with a button inside on top of a listview. It works fine. But the problem is the OnClick listener of the button is not triggered. And I see that the contents of the listview are displayed on top of the button (and the linearlayout). Here is the xml

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutOrdersDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"        
            android:background="#cc503F7F"                              
            >

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"                 
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewOrdersAddItem"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_orders_add_item"            
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/listViewOrderDetails"                   
                >

            </ListView>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

and here's the code just to test if the listener would be triggered, but it does not.

```
imageViewOrdersAddItem = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewOrdersAddItem);
    //imageViewOrdersAddItem.bringToFront();
    imageViewOrdersAddItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AppMessages.showMessage(OrdersActivity.this, "ADD BUTTON CLICKED", "ADD");
        }
    });
```

I have also tried .bringToFront() as suggested in other SO threads, but it doesn't work.

When i click the button, the listitem is the one that lights up (gets highlighted).

thanks in advance.

Comment: try to put layout inside headerview of listview and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a RelativeLayout the elements declared after a particular element are higher in z order than the ones previously defined unless ordering and alignment is specified. All the clicks are being consumed by the listview. Just reorder your xml layout to this.

```
       <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutOrdersDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        
        android:background="#cc503F7F"                              
        >

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listViewOrderDetails"                   
            >

        </ListView>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"                 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageViewOrdersAddItem"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_orders_add_item"            
                />
        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That results in the following error: E/AndroidRuntime(9105): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycomp.mysystem/com.mycomp.mysystem.OrdersActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView

Comment: I closed Eclipse and everything is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the listview is directly underneath the linearlayout and overriding the onclick of the button.

What you can do it set the proper layout of the ListView to by setting the linearlayout an **id** and placing the listview underneath the linearlayout using `layout_below`:

```
<LinearLayout 
               android:id="@+id/linearlayoutbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"                 
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewOrdersAddItem"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_orders_add_item"            
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayoutbutton"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/listViewOrderDetails"                   
                >

            </ListView>
```

Comment: That's what I already have. I you mean that I should add the listview first, followed by the Linearlayout, then an exception occurs saying E/AndroidRuntime(9105): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycomp.mysystem/com.mycomp.mysystem.OrdersActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView

Comment: @DiegoBandido then remove align parent bottom